# MOXy - StackOverflowError when bootstrapping JAXBContext with a self-containing class

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm trying to use the EclipseLink MOXy JAXB implementation to umarshal some XML data. I have the following annotated class, which has a member of its own type:

```
package stackoverflow.q19191209;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Item")
public class Item
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    @XmlID
    private String m_name;

    @XmlAttribute(name="parent")
    @XmlIDREF 
    private Item m_parent;
}
```

This class is listed in jaxb.index.  When I attempt to bootstrap my JAXBContext:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("stackoverflow.q19191209");
```

it hangs for a second, and then gives me a StackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:820)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:820)
    at java.util.HashMap.newValueIterator(HashMap.java:843)
    at java.util.HashMap$Values.iterator(HashMap.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.hasTextMapping(AnnotationsProcessor.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.hasTextMapping(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4003)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.hasTextMapping(AnnotationsProcessor.java:4003)
...
```

This does not happen when I use the default JAXB provider - it unmarshals correctly, and all relationships are correctly established.  Is this a MOXy bug?

I've tried JDK 1.6.0_25 and JDK 1.7.0_21, and MOXy versions 2.5.0, 2.5.1, and 2.6.0 - same results.

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

### UPDATE

A fix for this issue has been checked into EclipseLink 2.5.2 and 2.6.0.  You can download a nightly build with this fix starting **October 11, 2013** from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I have been able to reproduce the issue that you are seeing.  You can use the following link to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/418730